# How to use Java8 in an elegant way to return a map of <Object, Long> from a List<Object> counting occurrence?

Tags: java, list

I know the title is a mouthful, so I will try to explain with an example.

I have a List. Chores have an id field which work as an identifier, but the list will contain many chores, some of which will have the same ID's. My goal is to return a Map<Chore, Long> where the long will count up the # of occurrences for the chore. For example:

```
List<Chore> choreList = new ArrayList<Chore>();
choreList.add(new Chore("1", "vacuum", "7-6-22");  //Numbers 1,2,3 are the ID's for each chore
choreList.add(new Chore("2", "dusting", "7-1-22");
choreList.add(new Chore("3", "mowing", "7-15-22");
choreList.add(new Chore("1", "vacuum", "7-14-22");
choreList.add(new Chore("1", "vacuum", "7-18-22");
choreList.add(new Chore("2", "dusting", "7-24-22");
```

Using this list and the Java8 stream function, I would like to return a Map<Chore, Long> that has the chore object, and the occurrences. So in case of Chore with the ID of "1", the long would be 3. For the chore with the ID of "2", the long would be 2... and so on.

I tried to find an elegant solution for this, but it looks like everyone can get something like the following:

```
    Map<String, Long> choresById = chores.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Chore::getId, Collectors.counting()));
```

How can I come up with the Map<Chore, Long> instead of Map<String, Long> (in which case the String is the ID?)

Comment: It seems strange to me to use the same ID to represent multiple chores. How can you identify which chore you're looking at if not by its id? Perhaps you need a unique ID and a separate property like `groupId`

Comment: The reason this is so hard, is that Chore doesn't match your model. Let's say you have in your list `{Chore("1", "vacuum", "7-6-22"), Chore("1", "vacuum", "7-15-22"), Chore("1", "vacuum", "7-24-22")}`. You want a Map with 1 entry in it, whose value is `3`, but what should the key be? Which one of these 3 chores? In stream API, if order is important, you mostly already lost the game. More generally, saying 'elegant' while working with stringly typed stuff is impossible - this code is ugly, I don't think it's worthwhile looking for 'elegance' in the stream API when there's low hanging fruit.

Comment: This is why producing a `Map<String, Long>` with as result of this example `["1", "3"]` IS easy - now we're no longer debating which of the many chores you want to use as key.

Answer (score 2):

Because `Chore` is being used as a key in a `Map`, it should implement an identity-based `equals()` (and `hashCode()`). This satisfies the requirements for partitioning with `groupBy()` as well, so you can can use `Function.identity()` as the key extractor.

```java
Map<Chore, Long> choreCounts = chores.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```

---

In response the the follow-up question,

> There are other properties on the Chores and I need to count them based on the Id. Will the partitioning still work in this case?

Yes, it would still work *if* `equals()` is identity-based. However, it seems like your model might be deficient.

The property added as an example of additional `Chore` properties appears to be a date, and I'm guessing the idea here is that each `Chore` records completion of a chore on a certain date. Additional information might include who did the chore or how long it took.

If that guess is correct, I would suggest creating separate classes to represent the chore itself and performance of the chore:

```java
class Chore {

    private final long id;
    private final String name;

    Chore(long id, String name) {
       if (id < 1) throw new IllegalArgumentException("id < 1: " + id);
       this.id = id;
       this.name = Objects.requireNonNull(name);
    }

    @Override
    public final int hashCode() {
       return Long.hashCode(id);
    }

    @Override
    public final boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return obj == this || obj instanceof Chore that && that.id == this.id;
    }

}

class ChoreRecord {
  
    private final Chore chore;
    private final LocalDate datePerformed;

    ...

    Chore getChore() {
      return chore;
    }

    ...

}
```

The idea here is that you really only need one instance of the vacuuming task, one of the dusting task, etc. But many `ChoreRecord` instances can point to the same instance of the vacuuming `Chore`, etc.

Then, you'd generate a `Map<Chore, Long>` from a `List<ChoreRecord>`, grouping by the `Chore` from each `ChoreRecord`:

```java
Map<Chore, Long> choreCounts = choreRecords.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ChoreRecord::getChore, Collectors.counting()));
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. The example was perhaps not the best here... There are other properties on the Chores and I need to count them based on the Id. Will the partitioning still work in this case? I will modify the original post to reflect my idea

Comment: @mistakesweremade Please consider my update.

Comment: This is a great response. I can see what you mean. However, assuming I can't create a separate class and decouple the additional information outside of ID/name etc. from the Chore class, do I have an option to do so using stream? I basically want to group by the ID, but use the Chore itself as the key in the map and the count as the values.

Comment: @mistakesweremade If you implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` similar to how I did here, depending only on the `id` of the `Chore`, it will work. It's only that it makes things a little weird if you want to use `Chore.equals()` for other purposes where the extra properties might matter. For example, when you get a count from the map that you generated, which instance of `Chore` will you use? It doesn't really matter, because only the `id` is tested, but it will just feel a little weird.

Comment: I see what you mean. I wanted to avoid doing that in case we ever want to compare Chores since this is kind of an edge case and I dont want to make an equals method that only satisfies this case and will not function as expected for other cases... I am wondering if it is possible to specify the key of the map as the Chore but groupBy on the ID's instead of the Chore itself, then get the count based on the group

Comment: @mistakesweremade No, the map key is whatever you use for grouping. You can't group on ID but make Chore the key using `groupBy()` directly. You could group by ID, then have a following step lookup a `Chore` by ID and build a new map with `Chore` as keys. But you specified "elegant" in your title; the only elegant solution I see is the compositional modeling I laid out in my answer.